# how to replace one character in a dictionary with a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, replace

I need to replace the character u'\u2019' with @. This is contained inside a dictionary (too big to be shown). What I need is a for loop that looks at all keys and values. What I tried is:

```
for v in a.items():
    v = v.replace('u'\u2019'', '@')
    print v
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: And it didn't work? You've got some `'` (single quotes) to many I think. Or at least in the wrong place.

Comment: Do you want to change keys? or values? or both?

Comment: both. but not the all key or value. just that character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
a = {
    k.replace(u'\u2019', '@'): v.replace(u'\u2019', '@')
    for k, v in a.iteritems()
}
```

Comment: why is the for loop in the dictionary? like shouldn't it be outside?

Comment: How would you replace only the value?

Comment: just use `k` instead of `k.replace(u'\u2019', '@')`